# Code working in D3-V3 not working in D3-V4

Tags: d3.js

I have to disable panning from mouse left button in d3-v4, it should pan only using mouse right button. My below code was working in d3-v3 but not in v4

```
        this.zoomListener = d3.zoom().on("start", this.zoomstart.bind(this)).on("zoom", this.zoom.bind(this)).on("end", this.zoomend.bind(this));
        const eventProxy = (fn: any) => {
            return () => {
                // Enable events if enableEvents=== true
                if (d3.event.which === 3) {
                    fn.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            };
        };
        this.parentSvg.call(this.zoomListener).on("dblclick.zoom", null);
        const mouseDownTarget = this.parentSvg.on("mousedown.zoom");
        this.parentSvg.on("mousedown.zoom", eventProxy(mouseDownTarget));
```

Does anyone know how to do it in V4

Comment: Have you checked the release notes for d3 v4? You might be using some outdated calls: [d3 v4 zoom API](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#zooming-d3-zoom)

Comment: This is built-into verson 4, see [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom_filter)

Comment: I tried below mentioned code.
this.zoomListener = d3.zoom().on("start", this.zoomstart.bind(this)).on("zoom", this.zoom.bind(this)).on("end", this.zoomend.bind(this)).filter(() => {
                if (d3.event.which === 3) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
   
But it suppresses the event which i used to do some other task.